# Setup Tor server on my Android

Tags: security, tor

How do I setup a Tor server on my Android tablet?

I can install the Orbot client, but how do I contribute to the tor network?

I have my tablet on a WiFi the most of the day so it would be nice to contribute to the bandwidh of the Tor network.

Comment: Did this solution work for you? It didn't for me as I am getting a "port unreachable error" . I want to put my grandfathered unlimited data plan to good use!

Answer (score 4):

Select the Settings button ([image: Orbot Settings button]) on the top-right corner. In the Settings screen, scroll down to the "Relays" section and tick the box next to "Relaying - Enable your device to be a non-exit relay". The relay will listen to port 9001 by default, but you can adjust that by changing the relay port.

[image: Screenshot of the Orbot Settings screen]